# Padding NSString not working in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, padding

I have used the solution of the following question to pad NSString [Padding NSString not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642096/padding-nsstring-not-working), but after adding this string to UITableViewCell the cell label wasn't padded correctly

here is the code i used for padding

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [question stringByPaddingToLength:50
                                                                                    withString:@" "
                                                                               startingAtIndex:0], answer];
```

this is what i got when printing cell text on console

```
(lldb) po cell.textLabel.text
Where was the NTD PSU installed                   5

(lldb) po cell.textLabel.text
Estimate of cable run distance.                   5

(lldb) po cell.textLabel.text
Uploaded Picture of NTD PSU Location.             No
```

but here is what i got in the table cell

[image]

any idea why there are difference?

Comment: The console uses a monospaced font (each character has the same pixel width), while the labels within the cells are using some variety of Helvetica. How are you computing this padding?

Comment: @oltman i have edited the question to add the code i used, now how could i insert the font into the equation?

Comment: @oltman I think your answer is a good workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the additional code you posted, I would break this out into two separate labels: the left-aligned text as one label and the right-aligned yes/no/number as another. This would allow you to achieve the effect you're after without having to worry about letter spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is in kerning.

I'd like to quote Wikipedia:

> In typography, kerning (less commonly mortising) is the process of
>   adjusting the spacing between characters in a proportional font,
>   usually to achieve a visually pleasing result. Kerning adjusts the
>   space between individual letter forms, while tracking (letter-spacing)
>   adjusts spacing uniformly over a range of characters.[1] In a
>   well-kerned font, the two-dimensional blank spaces between each pair
>   of characters all have a visually similar area.

More on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning